# Диалог в диалоге

Tags: прямая-речь, диалог

Всем добрый день!.. Не подскажет лит кто-нибудь, как правильно оформляется высказывание, находящееся внутри диалоговой реплики, напр.:

– Там – Брехов и его замы. М. сразу же уехал,
ниxего не сказав. Видно, будет ждать, чем закончится «инцидент». Все осуждают Ваше «выступление». Г. прямо так и сказал К. И. Брехову:

– Ты сам воспитал этого волчонка. Теперь
тебе придется самому решать, что с ним делать.

Допустимо ли это высказывание оформить в виде двух диалоговых реплик (то есть так, как есть), или лучше оформить второе предложение как прямую речь (то есть с кавычками)?

Большое спасибо!..

Answer (score 1):

Это не диалог в диалоге, а цитата (чужие слова) внутри реплики.
Предложение, приведенное дословно и со "словами говорения", оформляется в виде прямой речи.

> **1.** Цитаты заключаются в кавычки. Если цитата оформляется как прямая речь, т. е. сопровождается словами автора, приводящего ее, то применяются соответствующие правила пунктуации...

*— ...Г. прямо так и сказал К. И. Брехову: "Ты сам воспитал этого волчонка. Теперь тебе придется самому решать, что с ним делать".*

> Ее пальцы, повозившись с застежкой сумки, достали пачку фотографий.
> — Муж мне пеняет: «Зачем ты это хранишь? Сожги». А я все думаю: может, на что-нибудь и сгодятся. Держите. — Она сунула фотографии Страйку; тот не стал отказываться. — Теперь пусть у вас хранятся. В Гейтсхед. Вот куда он поехал.
> Р. Гэлбрейт. На службе зла

> Феликс ушел; в ресторан уже начали прибывать первые посетители.
> — Ну что ж, — заметил я. — Миллионы людей также скажут: «Трудно поверить… Прямо в доме Ниро Вулфа!» Но, возможно, некоторые заявят, что поверить в это не так уж и трудно. Не знаю, что хуже.
> Р. Стаут. Семейное дело

[Кавычки при цитатах](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=164#pp164)